# Superuser says I raised two flags, but I only raised one

Tags: support

I've noticed this problem for a couple months now, but I thought it might have been a fluke.

Whenever I vote to close a question, when I click the flag button again to double check it was flagged, it shows that I voted to close for another reason **and** it was voted as duplicate:

[image]

I never voted to close "as duplicate". I did it for another reason. Did I break SU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are reasons to put the question on hold, so they count as the same thing.

All other flag reasons just call moderators attention to it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my view on this is that both lead to the question being closed or put on hold. So, either flagging for duplicate or flagging to be closed for another reason will disable the next option.